# Debugging of MapReduce using Hadoop 2.4.1 in Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I want to debug the code locally in Hadoop 2.4.1 version. I am confused with what Jar files I have to include.

I have tried with adding jar files present in `hadoop2.4.1/share/common`, `hadoop2.4.1/share/mapreduce` and `hadoop2.4.1/share/mapreduce/lib`. But I am getting few errors. I want to know exactly which Jar files are needed for debugging in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm trying to do this without any success.

Comment: No not yet. For debugging in eclipse I am using hadoop1.2 version and adding jars from lib and 3 other jars